# neo4j - performance of query to match nodes with a common relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a database from twitter data and have a relationship between Users and Places like:

```
(:User)-[:WAS_AT]-> (p:Place)
```

There are 610.464 relationships of that type, between 59.257 Users and 823 Places.

I want to get all the users who were in the same place:

```
MATCH q=(u1:User)-[:WAS_AT]->(:Place)<-[:WAS_AT]-(u2:User)
RETURN q
```

That query has not finished after more than two hours, what I am doing wrong?

I tried adding an index to the users but that not improved the efficiency.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is trying to get every distinct *pair* of visits to the same `Place`. So if there were N visits to a `Place`, you are trying to get `N*(N-1)` paths. And you are trying to do that for each and every `Place`.

What you actually want is to get is a list of distinct `Users` who visited the same `Place` (which will be at most N in size). Here is how you can do that:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:WAS_AT]->(place:Place)
RETURN place, COLLECT(DISTINCT u) AS users
```

The `DISTINCT` option is only needed if a `User` can have multiple `WAS_AT` relationships to the same `Place`.